# What is the name of this plumbing fitting?

Tags: plumbing

Recently I've bough a domestic reverse osmosis system and it got following bit used to feed the water: [image: plumbing piece 1/2]

It's g1/2 pipe with a small hole (12mm) in it.

I'd like to use it between brass water pipe and washing machine (I am renting so I can't alter existing plumbings), but they are 3/4 thread.

Can someone tell what's the name of this piece? Otherwise it's really hard to find something similar on web.

Thanks

Comment: most likey a custom peace. i dough there is a name for it

Comment: closest thing I can think of is a type of run tee, but yeah looks custom. It'd be easy to make granted you have a 12mm tap

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess I will have to use a "Self Piercing Saddle Valve Clamp" https://www.amazon.co.uk/Reverse-Osmosis-Piercing-Connection-Connects/dp/B0049GPEPW/  after all. (or to buy 2 adapters 3/4->1/2 and then 1/2 to 3/4) :(